# Android REORDER_TO_FRONT user new Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, flags

When I start an Activity A using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, and call `Intent intent = getIntent();`, I get the Intent that was used for the first creation of the Activity and not the one that was created with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag.

I want change the display based on the Extras of the Intent. Is there any way to either get the newly created Intent or change the Extras of the old intent?

Edit: Requested Example

Start Activity A with Intent A and Extras A -> go to another Activity X -> Call Activity A with Intent B (`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`) and Extras B

Now in Activity A, I would like to get Intent B when I call `getIntent()`, but I always get Intent A. It would also be okay, to just change the Extras from A to B

Comment: I am looking through the other intent flags that exist and FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED looks promising. This is just a shot in the dark though cause I am not on my dev machine right now: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT

Comment: Seems not to alter the behaviour. I'm still getting the intent from the first creation.

Comment: Could you explain what exact behavior you want? Itd probably be more clear if you give an example with activities 'A', 'B', 'C' etc and the flow you want between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I have a solution. If you start activity A with the flag [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) then it will destroy anything on the backstack on top of Activity A (Activity X in this case) and start Activity A with a new intent. I tried this out on my machine and it worked.

If you want Activity X to stick around so that your backstack then looks like "X -> A" Then you can override `onNewIntent()` in Activity A to capture the new intent and set it and keep using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to start the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  setIntent(intent);
  // Parse intent info both here and in onCreate()!
}
```

Just note that if you do this, and go back and forth between activity X and A your backstack will then look like: "X -> X -> X -> .... -> A" since X will chill on the backstack and A will just keep moving to the front.

Comment: Went for the second option, works perfectly, thanks!